# PHP Get 3 first alphabetic word in string

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the first 3 characters (of a month name) in a string if it exist then to echo it.

I know That I need to use regex but I didn't success.

```
$date = the_time(get_option( 'date_format' )); // April 21, 2014
preg_match_all('/^[a-z][a-z ]/', $date, $arr);
$month = array_slice(array_unique($arr[0]),0,3);

//will output: "Apr"
```

Comment: Your example lacks input data and the expected output.

Comment: Searched SO with: 'first alphabetic word in string' found 618 results

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z]+)/', $date, $arr);
$month = array_slice(array_unique($arr[1]),0,3);
```

Comment: In your example it works. But with my $date var it output nothing... I think it come from my var. I need to convert it to a string maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex ^([a-zA-Z]{3}) to match the first 3 chars (uppercase and lowercase) of a string. You can test it here :
http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94975

```
$date = 'April 21, 2014'; // April 21, 2014
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]{3})/', $date, $result);
var_dump($result[0]);
```